# facebook manage_pages alternative in v7.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

in earlier version of graph api they had manage_pages hook now they have depreciated that.

as far as the documentation says, we have to use 4 different request for using those permission now.

```
pages_manage_metadata
pages_manage_posts
pages_read_engagement
pages_read_user_content
```

is there any way we can use manage_pages ?? as these above permission  requires lot of hard work like signing contract with facbook etc

any help will be great.
manage_pages was great feature

Comment: It's difficult and convoluted no matter what. I think you need to use pages_manage_posts as I'm going through the same headache and haven't figured it out yet. The following page has been very helpful in the past before my fb post method broke recently: https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2017/11/25/csharp-dotnet-core-publish-facebook/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2020/05/05/introducing-graph-api-v7-marketing-api-v7/) by facebook mentioned in [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-manage_pages):

> Developers that already have access to manage_pages and publish_pages will be automatically migrated to the relevant, new permissions by June 1, 2020, and access will remain undisrupted.
>
> Developers with no existing access to manage_pages or publish_pages should actively monitor their app dashboard for the new permissions as they begin rolling out today. By June 1, 2020, all developers will see the new permissions and are encouraged to apply. After this date, applications for manage_pages and publish_pages will be unavailable and no longer reviewed.

Relevant part is they have mentioned that **developers that already have access to `manage_pages` will be automatically migrated**, so there is no way you can use `manage_pages` after June 1, 2020.